# Is Impala nested data available ?

Tags: hadoop, cloudera-cdh, impala

according to this http://impala.io/overview.html, impala 2.1 should support nested data.
I am using impala 2.1.1 but didn't find any documentation about nested data. Does anyone know when nested data will be supported by Impala?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Impala 2.1 does not support nested data. Note that the overview page you referenced lists these features under 'Impala 2.1 ***and Beyond***'. We're currently working on it for an upcoming release this year.